# Can i transit through the US when working on a cruise ship with a B1/b2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, paperwork

as a crew member from South Africa working a cruise line. I normally have a C1/D visa, however I would also like to spend either a week or two at the end of my contract exploring a few places in the USA before flying home.

My C1/D visa is up for renewal... Should I get a B1/B2 visa instead and will it all me to transit to the vessels?

Comment: I don't know if you'd be allowed to arrive into the US _working_ on a cruise ship without a visa that allows you to work.  A B1 visa doesn't allow you to work in the US

Answer (score 7):

A C1/D visa lets you stay in the US for 29 days and then leave on another vessel. So that will be enough - no need to apply for a B visa.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/crewmember-visa.html

> Crewmember (D) visas are nonimmigrant visas for persons working on board commercial sea vessels or international airlines in the United States, providing services required for normal operation and intending to depart the United States on the same vessel or any other vessel within 29 days. If you travel to the United States to join the vessel you will work on, in addition to a crewmember (D) visa, you also need a transit (C-1) visa or a combination C-1/D visa.

Comment: I added a `.gov` source to this.